# Simplify boolean expression containing potentially undefined variables

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I have a boolean expression defined as such :

```
const actif =
  this.props.configuration &&
  this.props.configuration.puissance &&
  this.props.configuration.puissance > 0
```

Depending on the component, this.props. might or not have `configuration` and `configuration` might or not have `puissance`. that’s why I need to do all these verifications.

using `{ has } from 'lodash'`, I have been able to simplify a bit already :

```
const actif =
      has(this.props.configuration, 'puissance') &&
      this.props.configuration.puissance > 0
```

But that’s not really satisfying either.

I tried something else. I know that JS allows you to do something like this :

```
(undefined || 4) === 4
```

which is true. unfortunately,

```
(this.props.configuration.puissance || undefined ) > 0
```

still gives me `Cannot read property 'puissance' of undefined`

Is there a simple way to do this comparison without having to check the entire tree of the object ? (and stop going any further in the tree if any step is undefined ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're using lodash already, how about using [lodash's `_.get()` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)?

```
const actif = _.get(this.props, "configuration.puissance", 0) > 0;
```

There is [a proposal for an optional chaining property in JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), but it's not made it into the language yet. When/if it does, you could do something like this:

```
const actif = this.props?.configuration?.puissance || 0 > 0;
```